# Overload function in for loop

Tags: julia

Assume I want to implement a module providing a custom vector class and overload all basic unary operations (round, ceil, floor, ...) for it. That should be rather straightforward in Julia:

```
module MyVectors
export MyVector
immutable MyVector{T} data::Vector{T} end

# This is the tricky part
for f in (:round, :ceil, :floor)
    @eval Base.$f(x::MyVector) = MyVector($f(x.data))
end

end
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: error compiling anonymous: syntax: prefix $ in non-quoted expression
 in include at ./boot.jl:245
 in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:128
while loading /home/masdoc/Desktop/Julia Stuff/MyVectors.jl, in expression starting on line 6
```

The problem seems to be the `Base.$f` part, for if I remove the `Base.` then it compiles. I want to overload `Base.round` and not create a new `round` method, however, so that's not a valid solution.

Comment: Your code works fine in versions `0.4+` and `0.5+`, this error only happens in version 0.3.x, I think it's caused by a syntax ambiguity, since using parenthesis solves this issue in version `0.3.11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Requests.jl](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/Requests.jl/blob/master/src/Requests.jl#L335) has what might be a good example of what you're trying to do, looping over symbols to generate function.  The following works for getting your loop working:

```
module MyVectors
export MyVector
immutable MyVector{T} data::Vector{T} end

# This is the tricky part
for f in (:round, :ceil, :floor)
    @eval (Base.$f)(x::MyVector) = MyVector(($f)(x.data))
end

end

using MyVectors
v = MyVector([3.4, 5.6, 6.7])

println(round(v))
println(ceil(v))
println(floor(v))
```

You might also find [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpNeNCGmyZE) video on metaprogramming and macros in julia useful.

Comment: Also if you `import Base.round, Base.ceil, Base.floor` then you can omit `Base.` and write `($f)(x::MyVector) = MyVector(($f)(x.data))`, I think recommended style for function overloading is this way.

Comment: You can also do `import Base: round, ceil, floor` or `importall Base`, I like the `@eval (Base.$f)` style better, because then I only have to keep track of the evaluated symbols in one place.